# start file manager in terminal window wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

Is there an easy way to start my File Manager in GUI as root? All I want to do is temporarily create/update some files and I want to do it through the GUI.

I am using a Raspberry Pi that is running Wheezy.

Comment: keep in mind that, this is really not a good idea to run a graphical app as root. i recommend you to learn using shell.

Comment: Disagree. Graphical file manager is just a tool. Can't do everything as a terminal does, but quite handy for simple copy/move/delete operations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

depends on your file manager.
for example:
sudo pcmanfm &>/dev/null &

Answer (score 5):

In Raspbian (Raspberry Debian)

from terminal console:

gksu pcmanfm   -> open file explorer as root

gksu leafpad   -> open file editor as root

Comment: gksu is preferred over sudo as it allows you to open even over remote X windows

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to open a file explorer in the current folder is `pcmanfm .`, which is basically the same as `open .` on MacOS system.